# 315 MHz receivers don't work correctly

Tags: arduino, rf, esp8266, esp32

I have two types of 315MHz receiver modules. One is based on SYN470r chip (rxb22 module) and the other one is much simpler (mx-rm-5v module) I have some problems with both.
The rxb22 works kinda ok and has a good range in receiving but it needs lots of repetition of signal to work (I mean you need to hold the remote button for half a second for it to work).
The other one (mx-rm-5v) doesn't have this problem and it detects signals instantly but the range is too low (about 1-2 centimeters)
Does anyone have a suggestion about how can I make any of the two work?

Comment: You haven't explained anything about how you drive the modules and, you haven't linked either of the modules' data sheets.

Comment: @Andyaka two modules are quite simple. I provided them GND and VCC (5V) and connected the DATA pin to one of my Arduino's GPIO pins and used a library called RC-SWITCH.

rxb22 datasheet: [link] http://tpelectronic.ir/datasheets/20141213163311953.pdf